# apache and ajp performance

Tags: apache-2.2, performance-tuning

I have an apache sitting in front of two tomcat app servers(one on the same physical server, the other on a different one) that does time consuming work(0.5 sec to 10sec per request).  The apache http server is getting killed by an average of 1 to 2 concurrent requests per second.  both Server spec is about 2GB of RAM.  Is there a way to optimize apache to handle the load?  any advise is welcome.

```
BalancerMember ajp://localhost:8009/xxxxxx
BalancerMember ajp://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:8009/xxxxxx
```

I keep getting the following in apache2.2 log:

```
[Mon Dec 28 00:31:02 2009] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
[Mon Dec 28 00:31:02 2009] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost)
```

Comment: If you posted the relevant Apache config you have it may offer more assistance. `BalancerMember` in and of itself is not enough. Is this within a `Proxy` declaration and are you using `RewriteRule`, `RedirectMatch` or `ProxyPass` to direct to the context on the Tomcat instances

Comment: Yeah we really need to see more detail to assess the situation.

Answer (score 0):

you could balance your load across the two servers. Try to give more load to the standalone tomcat. You'll find same examples here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

The error message looks like your tomcat isn't giving back any response. Did you take a look at your tomcat logs? Perhaps the tomcats have some trouble and apache is keeping connections open. This could also be a source for apache givving up. Do you have mod_status installed on your apache? This could give you some additional hints.

Christian